# Updating a record and then displaying it in iron router function

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I've got the following iron-router setup with meteor:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('decoded', {
    path: '/id/:id',
    data: function() {
      message.update({_id: this.params.id._id}, {$set: {read: "1"}});
      return message.findOne({id: this.params.id});
    }
});
```

Take note that I am storing an id, which is not the same as _id that mongodb generates.
In my template I have `{{subject}}`

On insert, the value of `read` is 0, when they visit the url /id/:id I want the value of `read` to be changed to 1, and then display the subject.

When I run it, I don't get any errors or anything. It displays my message, just fine, but doesn't update the `read` field.

Comment: Wouldn't the value of "this.params.id._id" be undefined?

Comment: When I type in an id (not _id) into the console manually by running ```message.findOne({id: "9913b0cc-fc79-495a-a5d5-55c8c22d7bb3"})._id```
I get ```"hzMnnLte6zygr7eim"``` so wouldn't what I have in the original code still work?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the case of the update statement you have you are trying to get the _id from the id param of the route (which is a string). That means _id is undefined and the update statement will do nothing. To fix it first find the message using the id param, get the _id like you mentioned in your comment, and use that to update the message.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing, though? I'm finding the id by this.params.id, then getting the _id by putting ._id at the end of it, then using it to try to update the document.

Comment: You're getting the id string in the URL by using this.params.id not the object in the collection. So you need to get the object in the collection first to get it's _id